# Unable to upload CHM file to SharePoint 2010

Tags: file-upload, attachments

I already went to Central Admin and took off CHM in the Defined Blocked Types list but I'm still unable to upload a CHM file to my SharePoint list.

I keep getting the default error msg: "The list item was saved, but one or more attachments could not be saved. (`<file location>`) has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators."

Can anyone help? Thanks!

I also wanted to upload an HTM file and it lets me do that but when I open it, it's blank and has 404 Error msgs on it.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I made a mistake. I had logged into my Central Admin, but when I went to Defined block file types, I was on a different web app server setting by default (upper right hand side). So I had originally made the changes on a site collection instead of my own. Problem fixed! Thanks!